# Reverse a string recursively in C - using a pointer to string only

Tags: c, string, pointers, recursion

i'm trying to reverse a string using recursion and a single pointer to that string.

My idea is to traverse the string from both edges, raising the pointer and inserting '\0's at the end of the string. For example - given a string 'abcde\0' - replace "chars" before the middle of the string, and insert '\0' after -> recursive calls -> when "stop condition" is reached, original string should be like this - 'edc\0\0\0' - and half of chars stored as temp variable, in stack. When turning back and popping the stack, these chars should overwrite the '\0' in reverse order. This is the idea.

This is my code so far, but I can't get it work - please help me understand, what do I miss. I have a '\0' in the middle of string that I can't figure out how to rewrite it. (I guess this is the major problem)
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void rev_str(char* _str);
int main()
{
    char str[]="abcde";
    puts("Str before:");
    puts(str);
    rev_str(str);
    puts("Str after");
    puts(str);
    return 0;
}

void rev_str(char* _str)
{
    int  len=strlen(_str);
    char temp=*_str;
    if(len>1)
    {
        *_str = _str[len-1];
        _str[len-1]='\0';
        rev_str(++_str);    
    } 
    _str[len-1]=temp;
}
```

Comment: This is, what, the 6th question about reversing a string recursively in C?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recursively reversing a string in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23878979/recursively-reversing-a-string-in-c)

Comment: [and quite a few others](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+reverse+string+recursion).

Comment: Also I would suggest reading up on debugging source. Single stepping through the code would hi-light the areas that are failing. Pen and paper, writing out the solution you are attempting, using simple blocks and breaking the problem down into much smaller steps.  Also getting the code to work, not using recursion - will at least allow you to prove your source. Development in stages. I'll stop waffling now! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I won't debug your code, however this might help you understand things better -

http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c-program-reverse-string

Examples taken from page -

**C program to reverse a string using pointers**

Now we will invert string using pointers or without using library function strrev.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int string_length(char*);
void reverse(char*);

main() 
{
   char string[100];

   printf("Enter a string\n");
   gets(string);

   reverse(string);

   printf("Reverse of entered string is \"%s\".\n", string);

   return 0;
}

void reverse(char *string) 
{
   int length, c;
   char *begin, *end, temp;

   length = string_length(string);
   begin  = string;
   end    = string;

   for (c = 0; c < length - 1; c++)
      end++;

   for (c = 0; c < length/2; c++)
   {        
      temp   = *end;
      *end   = *begin;
      *begin = temp;

      begin++;
      end--;
   }
}

int string_length(char *pointer)
{
   int c = 0;

   while( *(pointer + c) != '\0' )
      c++;

   return c;
}
```

**C program to reverse a string using recursion**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char*, int, int);

int main()
{
   char a[100];

   gets(a);

   reverse(a, 0, strlen(a)-1);

   printf("%s\n",a);

   return 0;
}

void reverse(char *x, int begin, int end)
{
   char c;

   if (begin >= end)
      return;

   c          = *(x+begin);
   *(x+begin) = *(x+end);
   *(x+end)   = c;

   reverse(x, ++begin, --end);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    rev_str(++_str);
```

This is the problem. You're modifying `_str` here so when you do `_str[len-1]=temp` at the end, you're writing to the wrong location. Change it to

```
    rev_str(_str + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the code `rev_str(++_str);` into `rev_str(_str+1);`. The `++_str` equal to `_str += 1`, it will change the pointer `char *_str`. But `_str+1` will only initialize the `formal param`, and will not change the 'char *str'. I hope this can help you.